# Does moving to PHP 7 require any system change to be done with Drush or from the GUI?

Tags: 8, drush

After moving a Drupal site from PHP 5.6 to 7.13, is it better to change something from the GUI or from Drush?

Comment: I had no problems myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no action that needs to be taken through the GUI or drush when you change PHP versions.

Answer (score 3):

It is plausible, though very unlikely, that there is something in the compiled container that has a dependency on the PHP version.  If you switch PHP versions, it is safest to to a

```
$ drush cr
```

to force a rebuild.

To my knowledge (and based on IRC conversations with people who know **way** more than I do), there is nothing in core that would require this, but it is possible that there is a contrib module that introduces a service that would require this.